# When response.data is an empty array:- Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am facing difficulty when I am using one axios request in another. Especially when the response.data array is empty. 
Whenever response.data array is empty it gives me this error:-

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of
>   undefined

I know many people have asked Uncaught but not with response.data
Here is my code:-

```
axios.get(URL+'/xyz?variable='+variablevalue, headerconfig)
    .then(response => {
     this.tempvariable= (response.data);
    axios.get(URL+'/abc?variable='+variablevalue,headerconfig)
        .then((response) => {
          this.tempvariable = (response.data);
          //inside for loop by using this.tempvariable
          this.some_variable= this.anothervari.reduce((a,b) => Number(a) > Number(b) ? a : b);
        })
        .catch(e => {
            alert(e.response.data);
        })       

    })
    .catch(e => {
        alert(e.response.data);
    })
```

Comment: What do you get on `console.log(response)`?

Comment: Do you know which line this error is being thrown from?

Comment: I think the problem is that you are using same variable (response) on both requests.

Comment: You should take a look at the response, do you find the data in it?

Comment: in console.log(response), I got this`{data: Array(0), status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}`

Comment: Either your ```response``` or ```e.response``` is ```undefined```.

Comment: @gillyhl yes its the last line  of second axios call ` .catch(e => {
        alert(e.response.data);
    })`

Comment: So your error being thrown by the promise won't have a response property in the object, so it's going to try and look for data on an undefined object. Instead of ```alert(e.response.data)``` do ```console.error(e)``` in both errors and see what gets printed

Comment: @gillyhl it is giving me an error at e.response.data at the second axios call

Comment: Have you changed the alert call to a console logging just the ```e``` object, nothing else? If so, what is the message?

Comment: @gillyhl this is the message I got when I change it to console.log:- `TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168715/discussion-between-gillyhl-and-juststartedprogramming).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error has come from the line `this.some_variable= this.anothervari.reduce((a,b) => Number(a) > Number(b) ? a : b);` that was missing in the original question.

You need to give the reduce function a starting value when reducing to an array, so change to this: `this.some_variable= this.anothervari.reduce((a,b) => Number(a) > Number(b) ? a : b, []);`

Answer (score 0):

The error could have happened during the request setup before any response was returned in which case the response object is undefined
https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors

Answer (score -1):

In case axios receives no response from the server, the error object has no response object. If you look at the example documentation [here](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors), you can see that while catching the error, they check if the response object exists or not. In your case, your request probably fails without never reaching the server so you don't have a response. In cases like this it is recommended to see if the response object exists before accessing it, as otherwise you will have an exception.

```js
    axios.get('/user/12345')
    .catch(function (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
      // that falls out of the range of 2xx
      console.log(error.response.data);
      console.log(error.response.status);
      console.log(error.response.headers);
    } else if (error.request) {
      // The request was made but no response was received
      // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
      // http.ClientRequest in node.js
      console.log(error.request);
    } else {
      // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
      console.log('Error', error.message);
    }
    console.log(error.config);
  });
```